# Deploy NextJS on Vercel - Website Production Error ENOENT Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, vercel

My code runs ok on localhost:

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

export default function createUserDir (tokenSignature: string) { 
    const pathToMakeDir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'notes', tokenSignature);
    fs.mkdirSync(pathToMakeDir, { recursive: true });    
}
```

As you can see I'm already using the **recursive flag**.

The error is the following:

```
2022-11-15T19:32:34.119Z    145c46ab-416c-4f5c-b881-80b9c623a5ac    ERROR   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/var/task/notes/jFlqLkrmIPOEnaiExiUN3ohlmJlH_GN2OD36fiQ9a2A'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1349:3)
    at createUserDir (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/133.js:252:45)
    at getServerSideProps (/var/task/.next/server/pages/index.js:93:76)
    at Object.renderToHTML (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:506:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async doRender (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:701:34)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.isManualRevalidate.isManualRevalidate (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:806:28)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:80:36 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/var/task/notes/jFlqLkrmIPOEnaiExiUN3ohlmJlH_GN2OD36fiQ9a2A',
  page: '/'
}
RequestId: 145c46ab-416c-4f5c-b881-80b9c623a5ac Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

This error does not makes sense since I'm already using the flag.

I'm using Next version 13.0.3 and Vercel runs Node 16.x

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue trying to call `fs` methods. Try adding `output: 'standalone'` to your `next.config.js`

```js
const nextConfig = {
  // ... other config here
  output: 'standalone'
}

export default nextConfig
```

Searching elsewhere it was recommended to add `nftTracing: true`, but it looks like it has been deprecated.

If the above doesn't work, trying checking out [this long GH issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8251)